# How to execute background Long Running tasks in React native (iOS)

Tags: javascript, react-native, background-task, long-running-processes, ios-background-mode

I have a case where I need to run a background task for at least 8-12 mins based on network bandwidth.

I searched a lot but can't find a way in React Native. I'm just wondering is it really not possible with react-native even at 2022 ?

Suggestions and solutions are welcome....!

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What are the specifications of the background task? Also, you could provide a sample code with your attempt as well as the code from which you will be writing this task. It's helpful when you provide more context.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-background-timer library to implement it, its working in android well. 

`BackgroundTimer.runBackgroundTimer(async () => {
       if (isUploadPhotoLoading == false && Jobs?.pendingJob?.data?.jobs.length > 0) {
              // performing API call for 8-12 mins
        }
    }, 5000) `
@chris